# How to print nodes in neo4j till a particular node

Tags: graph, neo4j, notifications, cypher

I have a database with nodes like

```
(A:User)-[:HAS_NOTIFICATION]->(B:Notification)-[:NEXT]->
(C:Notification)-[:NEXT]->[D:Notification]-[:NEXT]->
(E:Notification) and so on
```

Now I want to print notifications for a particular user till last notification already sent to user. Like If  I have already sent notifications till "D" now I have to send notifications "B, C" which are not sent. So I have to write a query which returns notification nodes till a particular node is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the last notification sent, you can do something like this :

```
MATCH 
 (:Person {id:"User_ID"})-[:HAS_NOTIFICATION]->(n1:Notification),
 (n2:Nofitication  { id:"LAST_NOTIFICATION_SENT"}),
  p=shortestPath((n1)-[*]->(n2))
RETURN 
  nodes(p)
```

Cheers

Comment: There are two small problems with this solution, like if a user has only one notification then it does not return any notification. Another problem is if I try to fetch new list of notifications then the new list also includes the last sent notification.